# cloud9 nodejs - Error: write EPROTO 140261073610560. and in localhost everything ok

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide, proxy-server

I have this script from :

https://github.com/No9/harmon/blob/master/examples/simple.js

and if i run it `node simple.js` in my localhost everything work well. but in my [cloud9](https://c9.io) account i get:

`Error: write EPROTO 140261073610560:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:`

[image]

so i can i fix it?

Comment: I notice that you're using HTTPS on c9, whereas the localhost is http. Does that make a difference in the outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the ports

> Cloud9 hosted workspaces now allow workspaces to listen on multiple
> ports. The following ports are supported (along with the urls they can
> be accessed from):
>
> 8080 -> https://-.c9users.io
>
> 8081 -> https://-.c9users.io:8081
>
> 8082 -> https://-.c9users.io:8082

https://docs.c9.io/docs/multiple-ports

so i replaced the `8000` to `8080` and `9000` to `8081`

and it works !

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, after fiddling for two days, (and even breaking the pipeline in between- due to playing around with node and npm versions), I came to the conclusion -  it was a server-side problem and so:

- Server was down, partially due to overloading (I was deploying on turbo 360)
  and so, refrain from changing your versions, you may break the pipeline.
- Try to deploy from a different network.
- just wait for a day or two, and the server (turbo 360 in my case) will work just fine.