# Nodejs request problem - Error: write EPROTO

Tags: node.js

- node: v10.19.0
- request: v2.88.2
- jsdom: v11.12.0

When I use my Nodejs app in my city home with optical fibre, everything is ok, but, when I use my Nodejs app at my summer house where I use mobile internet (T-mobile), I get this error (probably because of the different operator) when attempting to access some pages.

```sh
Error: write EPROTO 140216527574848:error:1414D172:SSL 
    routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong signature 
    type:../ssl/t1_lib.c:1145:
```

Honestly, I have no idea what is going on. The only similar topic I have found is this:
[cloud9 nodejs - Error: write EPROTO 140261073610560. and in localhost everything ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39954826/cloud9-nodejs-error-write-eproto-140261073610560-and-in-localhost-everything)

```
var requestData = request(url, function(err, resp, HTMLdata) {
    if (!err && resp.statusCode === 200) {
        console.log('Request success \n');
    }
});
```

I have a router from T-mobile (Huawei which does not have a bridge option).

So, if this is a port problem I can access the router, but, what should I change?